# Why do I always have to click the new hat notification away at least twice before it stays gone?

Tags: bug, design, notifications, winter-bash, winter-bash-2016

When you get a new inbox message, the red indicator goes away if you click on the drop-down and click away. Same with the rep tracker. But Winterbash is not so: you have to repeat the process, sometimes more than once, before the icon will disappear. This is irritating, like having to turn the light off twice before it actually goes off.

Comment: I thought it was related to multiple sites I had open and that those notifications don't clear across domains. +1 for the question though.

Comment: @PatrickHofman: It seems to happen even on a single site; contrariwise, after repeating once or twice, it clears across all sites.

Comment: Experienced the same issue muhself.